# Typescript: how to map array of types to distinct arguments via advanced types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Current API

```
type Array1 = [MyArgs   , MyExample] // assuming types `MyArgs` and `MyExample` exist
type Array2 = [MyExample, MyArgs   ]
type ValidArray = Array1 | Array2 | ... // assuming no validArray like [MyArgs, MyArgs] and [MyExample, MyExample]

const f = (va: ValidArray) => {...}
const myargs    : MyArgs    = ...
const myexample : MyExample = ...

f([myargs,myexample])
```

Instead of what you see in the last row of the current API, I want this API:

```
f(myargs,myexample)
```

**without losing the information, that the 2 arguments together have to be one of the type of the enumerated arrays in ValidArrays**

So, for example I don't want to accept these as valid argument lists:

```
f(myargs   ,myargs   )
f(myexample,myexample)
```

I assume there is an advanced typescript technique to map (or spread?) the arrays of types to the argument list like that, but I couldn't find it out.

Comment: Spreading like: ```const f = (...va: ValidArray)``` solves THIS particular example, but introduces other problems, I'd be more interested in a cleaner solution.

Comment: What kind of problems does it introduce? You might want to update your question to specify the additional requirements.

Comment: I might want to use additional arguments.

Comment: Smth like this? `f(myargs,myexample, other, args, to, follow)`? And with a variable number of additional args? I updated my answer to allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question (and additional comment) correctly, `const fn = (...args: [...ValidArray, ...any[]]) => ...` should be what you want. ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAjFAvFA2ogNFATAXQChRJYFdUMAiGKnKgISqOPGgDUBDAGwEsATeHE4hKQ5AB8ycXITkBjAPYA7AM7AoAM2WUAFADpDnOAHNVALgyH9XPoIQic1zspDp8+AJSXlAVwC2AEYQcKgAfFDGZvrcEMomwAAWcgD0KVAAKokQqtAA7opwANaESmoawDnAyGjauth4nqUq6lCV6hS1yro0dFCMVE1lre3AAMyUdb30TPQu-H1Uikkhi1Gqg6npGWxQIXCFqs3lWpy83DVa3Q0DQy0ammfcnVc9tDi4dyeP5xNd9TgbvNFstsnA1qYNp4gA))

```
type Arr1 = [1, 2]
type Arr2 = ["A", "B"]

type ValidArray = Arr1 | Arr2


const fn = (...args: [...ValidArray, ...any[]]): number => args.length

// These work
const test1 = fn(1, 2)
const test2 = fn("A", "B")
const test3 = fn("A", "B", "and", "other", "args")

// Type errors
const fail1 = fn(1, "B")
const fail2 = fn("A", 2)
const fail3 = fn(1, 1, "and", "other", "args")
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, this is awesome! BIG KUDOS to you! I might use it as [...ValidArray, ...MyFunctionSignature[]], but you nailed it. If there's more upcoming necessary features I might let you know if its okay to you. :) May I ask how did you find out / how do you practice these advanced stuff? I'd be happy to learn, but not too many GOOD resources out there. :/

Comment: Can you please update the playground link?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Link is updated.

Comment: Regarding the learning: I usually follow the TS roadmap: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap. Or I learn from googling and asking here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your insights!